# Grouping and Ordering result to pick the most recent record in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, relational-database, sql-order-by

I have the following query written in such a way it returns the data I need:

```
SELECT SLCA.CustomerAccountNumber, SLCD.DefaultEmail, SOR.DocumentDate, SLST.*
FROM SLCustomerAccount AS SLCA
INNER JOIN SOPOrderReturn AS SOR ON SOR.CustomerID = SLCA.SLCustomerAccountID
INNER JOIN SLCustomerContactDefaultsVw AS SLCD ON SLCD.SLCustomerAccountID = SLCA.SLCustomerAccountID
LEFT OUTER JOIN MMS182SLStatus AS SLST ON SLST.Customer = SLCA.SLCustomerAccountID
WHERE SLCD.IsDefaultRole = 1 AND SLCD.DefaultEmail IS NOT NULL AND SLCD.DefaultEmail <> ''
 AND SLCD.DefaultEmail = '...major@live.co.uk'
 AND SLST.[Status] IS NULL
ORDER BY SOR.DocumentDate DESC
```

The only issue is, this email I am using in the where filter yields multiple results like this (albeit being correct):

[image]

How can I use `group by` to remove duplicate rows, so I only have get one record for the most recent DocumentDate?

I know i can do `TOP 1` but this is not what I need. Because, I am testing the query now by scoping to one particular email that has duplicate. Later, I need to run this query on all records without this line `AND SLCD.DefaultEmail = '...major@live.co.uk'` - so you can see why I can't use `TOP 1`.

When I tried to use `group by` like this:

```
SELECT MAX(SLCA.CustomerAccountNumber), MAX(SLCD.DefaultEmail), MAX(SOR.DocumentDate), MAX(SLST.MMS182SLStatus), MAX(SLST.Customer), MAX(SLST.[Status])
FROM SLCustomerAccount AS SLCA
INNER JOIN SOPOrderReturn AS SOR ON SOR.CustomerID = SLCA.SLCustomerAccountID
INNER JOIN SLCustomerContactDefaultsVw AS SLCD ON SLCD.SLCustomerAccountID = SLCA.SLCustomerAccountID
LEFT OUTER JOIN MMS182SLStatus AS SLST ON SLST.Customer = SLCA.SLCustomerAccountID
WHERE SLCD.IsDefaultRole = 1 AND SLCD.DefaultEmail IS NOT NULL AND SLCD.DefaultEmail <> ''
 AND SLCD.DefaultEmail = '...major@live.co.uk'
 AND SLST.[Status] IS NULL
GROUP BY SLCD.DefaultEmail
ORDER BY MAX(SOR.DocumentDate) DESC
```

It returns the wrong result:

[image]

I was expecting it to return this record:

[image]

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
with q as (<your query here without the `order by`>)
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             row_number() over (partition by DefaultEmail order by documentdate desc) as seqnum
      from q
     ) q
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried it like this: http://pastebin.com/GCssEkpC and it's still returning the wrong result as shown above. However, If I remove the `group by` clause, it returns 2 records (for each variation of the customeraccountnumber). Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: @Latheesan You must take query from the very beginning of your question and paste in `with q as (<here>)...`. For 5 rows from your output will be shown only two on recent date.

Comment: I tried that, it does show **two** records like this: http://i.imgur.com/hAWlUqY.png - this is not what I need. I need one result per email, sorted by most recent `DocumentDate`, therefore I should have gotten the result with customeraccountnumber `JAC006` as per my original question. i.e. I am trying to use `order by` AND `group by` _email_.

Comment: @Latheesan Use this in query from answer `row_number() over (partition by DefaultEmail order by documentdate desc) as seqnum`

Comment: Brilliant! thank you very much - this did the trick. I tested it with multiple emails also and it appears to work as intended.